# How to use "touch" command to update file timestamp using blobfuse2?

Tags: linux, azure-data-lake, fuse

I setup a mounting point to an adls storage account using blobfuse2. The mounting works fine and I'm able to create new files and copy files using linux commands (touch,  cp).

Problem is when I execute "touch" command on an existing file, the timestamp is only reflected locally.

**OS**:

```
NAME="CentOS Linux"
VERSION="7 (Core)"
ID="centos"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="7"
PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 7 (Core)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:centos:centos:7"
HOME_URL="https://www.centos.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.centos.org/"

CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT="CentOS-7"
CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT_VERSION="7"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="centos"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7"
```

**blobfuse2.yaml**:

```
allow-other: true
 
logging:
  type: base
  level: log_debug
  file-path: ./blobfuse2.log
 
components:
  - libfuse
  - stream
  - azstorage
  
libfuse:
  attribute-expiration-sec: 120
  entry-expiration-sec: 120
  negative-entry-expiration-sec: 240
   
stream:
  block-size-mb: 100
  blocks-per-file: 3
  cache-size-mb: 1024
 
attr_cache:
  timeout-sec: 7200
 
azstorage:
  type: adls
  account-name: MASK
  account-key: MASK
  endpoint: https://MASK.blob.core.windows.net
  mode: key
  container: input
```

**Mount command**:

```
blobfuse2 mount input2 --config-file=blobfuse2.yaml
```

**Storage and mount before commands**:
[image]
[image]

**Storage and mount after commands**:
[image]
[image]

As can be seen, both the new file and the existing file were shown with new timestamps on the mount point, but on the adls storage the existing file is not showing the timestamp updated but the new file can be seen there.

Already tried playing with the cache configuration, using file_cache instead of stream, etc.

**Blobfuse logs**:

```
Mon Mar 13 16:47:43 UTC 2023 : blobfuse2[19739] : LOG_TRACE [datalake.go (376)]: Datalake::GetAttr : name new_file.txt
Mon Mar 13 16:47:43 UTC 2023 : blobfuse2[19739] : LOG_TRACE [libfuse_handler.go (579)]: Libfuse::libfuse_create : new_file.txt
Mon Mar 13 16:47:43 UTC 2023 : blobfuse2[19739] : LOG_TRACE [read_write.go (68)]: Stream::CreateFile : name=new_file.txt, mode=-rw-r--r--
Mon Mar 13 16:47:43 UTC 2023 : blobfuse2[19739] : LOG_TRACE [azstorage.go (344)]: AzStorage::CreateFile : new_file.txt
Mon Mar 13 16:47:43 UTC 2023 : blobfuse2[19739] : LOG_TRACE [datalake.go (246)]: Datalake::CreateFile : name new_file.txt
Mon Mar 13 16:47:43 UTC 2023 : blobfuse2[19739] : LOG_TRACE [block_blob.go (267)]: BlockBlob::CreateFile : name new_file.txt
Mon Mar 13 16:47:43 UTC 2023 : blobfuse2[19739] : LOG_TRACE [block_blob.go (912)]: BlockBlob::WriteFromBuffer : name new_file.txt
Mon Mar 13 16:47:44 UTC 2023 : blobfuse2[19739] : LOG_TRACE [datalake.go (559)]: Datalake::ChangeMod : Change mode of file new_file.txt to -rw-r--r--
Mon Mar 13 16:47:44 UTC 2023 : blobfuse2[19739] : LOG_TRACE [libfuse_handler.go (597)]: Libfuse::libfuse_create : new_file.txt, handle 9
Mon Mar 13 16:47:44 UTC 2023 : blobfuse2[19739] : LOG_TRACE [datalake.go (376)]: Datalake::GetAttr : name new_file.txt
Mon Mar 13 16:47:44 UTC 2023 : blobfuse2[19739] : LOG_TRACE [libfuse_handler.go (734)]: Libfuse::libfuse_flush : new_file.txt, handle: 9
Mon Mar 13 16:47:44 UTC 2023 : blobfuse2[19739] : LOG_TRACE [libfuse_handler.go (1048)]: Libfuse::libfuse_utimens : new_file.txt
Mon Mar 13 16:47:44 UTC 2023 : blobfuse2[19739] : LOG_TRACE [datalake.go (376)]: Datalake::GetAttr : name new_file.txt
Mon Mar 13 16:47:44 UTC 2023 : blobfuse2[19739] : LOG_TRACE [libfuse_handler.go (734)]: Libfuse::libfuse_flush : new_file.txt, handle: 9
Mon Mar 13 16:47:44 UTC 2023 : blobfuse2[19739] : LOG_TRACE [libfuse_handler.go (783)]: Libfuse::libfuse_release : new_file.txt, handle: 9
Mon Mar 13 16:47:44 UTC 2023 : blobfuse2[19739] : LOG_TRACE [azstorage.go (393)]: AzStorage::CloseFile : new_file.txt
Mon Mar 13 16:47:52 UTC 2023 : blobfuse2[19739] : LOG_TRACE [libfuse_handler.go (613)]: Libfuse::libfuse_open : 23-02-09-04-05-29-000-19-DATASET1-L3_Mac4555.csv.gz
Mon Mar 13 16:47:52 UTC 2023 : blobfuse2[19739] : LOG_WARNING [libfuse_handler.go (628)]: Libfuse::libfuse_open : Flags (8801) not supported to open 23-02-09-04-05-29-000-19-DATASET1-L3_Mac4555.csv.gz when write back cache is on. Ignoring unsupported flags.
Mon Mar 13 16:47:52 UTC 2023 : blobfuse2[19739] : LOG_TRACE [read_write.go (84)]: Stream::OpenFile : name=23-02-09-04-05-29-000-19-DATASET1-L3_Mac4555.csv.gz, flags=34818, mode=-rwxr-xr-x
Mon Mar 13 16:47:52 UTC 2023 : blobfuse2[19739] : LOG_TRACE [azstorage.go (369)]: AzStorage::OpenFile : 23-02-09-04-05-29-000-19-DATASET1-L3_Mac4555.csv.gz
Mon Mar 13 16:47:52 UTC 2023 : blobfuse2[19739] : LOG_TRACE [datalake.go (376)]: Datalake::GetAttr : name 23-02-09-04-05-29-000-19-DATASET1-L3_Mac4555.csv.gz
Mon Mar 13 16:47:52 UTC 2023 : blobfuse2[19739] : LOG_TRACE [libfuse_handler.go (661)]: Libfuse::libfuse_open : 23-02-09-04-05-29-000-19-DATASET1-L3_Mac4555.csv.gz, handle 10
Mon Mar 13 16:47:52 UTC 2023 : blobfuse2[19739] : LOG_TRACE [libfuse_handler.go (734)]: Libfuse::libfuse_flush : 23-02-09-04-05-29-000-19-DATASET1-L3_Mac4555.csv.gz, handle: 10
Mon Mar 13 16:47:52 UTC 2023 : blobfuse2[19739] : LOG_TRACE [libfuse_handler.go (1048)]: Libfuse::libfuse_utimens : 23-02-09-04-05-29-000-19-DATASET1-L3_Mac4555.csv.gz
Mon Mar 13 16:47:52 UTC 2023 : blobfuse2[19739] : LOG_TRACE [datalake.go (376)]: Datalake::GetAttr : name 23-02-09-04-05-29-000-19-DATASET1-L3_Mac4555.csv.gz
Mon Mar 13 16:47:52 UTC 2023 : blobfuse2[19739] : LOG_TRACE [libfuse_handler.go (734)]: Libfuse::libfuse_flush : 23-02-09-04-05-29-000-19-DATASET1-L3_Mac4555.csv.gz, handle: 10
Mon Mar 13 16:47:52 UTC 2023 : blobfuse2[19739] : LOG_TRACE [libfuse_handler.go (783)]: Libfuse::libfuse_release : 23-02-09-04-05-29-000-19-DATASET1-L3_Mac4555.csv.gz, handle: 10
Mon Mar 13 16:47:52 UTC 2023 : blobfuse2[19739] : LOG_TRACE [azstorage.go (393)]: AzStorage::CloseFile : 23-02-09-04-05-29-000-19-DATASET1-L3_Mac4555.csv.gz
Mon Mar 13 16:48:47 UTC 2023 : blobfuse2[19739] : LOG_TRACE [libfuse_handler.go (415)]: Libfuse::libfuse_opendir : 
Mon Mar 13 16:48:47 UTC 2023 : blobfuse2[19739] : LOG_TRACE [azstorage.go (278)]: AzStorage::StreamDir : Path , offset 0, count 5000
Mon Mar 13 16:48:47 UTC 2023 : blobfuse2[19739] : LOG_TRACE [datalake.go (429)]: Datalake::List : prefix , marker 
Mon Mar 13 16:48:48 UTC 2023 : blobfuse2[19739] : LOG_DEBUG [azstorage.go (299)]: AzStorage::StreamDir : Retrieved 2 objects with  marker for Path 
Mon Mar 13 16:48:48 UTC 2023 : blobfuse2[19739] : LOG_TRACE [libfuse_handler.go (440)]: Libfuse::libfuse_releasedir : , handle: 11
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you try to add disable-writeback-cache: true in your blobfuse2.yaml file below to the libfuse property and then reboot the VM ?